# How to draw multiple plots in one frame using python that Y-axis can see properly?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have written a python code for multiple plots in one frame using matpoltlib. When I see my image, Y-axis does not show the title proper way (actually it overlap or cut by number etc) and X-axis should have one title because X-axis is the same for all four (temp, potential, total, pressure). I have uploaded the image. if you can not see it. please let me know.

initial.txt file looks like this:

```
   0      1865.74   -388642.31   -362596.65   -57421.263 
 100    100.39272   -388659.69   -387258.21   -68103.868 
 200    100.34027   -388677.95    -387277.2   -68090.633 
 300    100.25494   -388696.92   -387297.36    -68081.08 
 400    100.28753   -388716.37   -387316.36   -68072.858 
 500    100.27897   -388736.41   -387336.52    -68067.56 
 600    100.27288   -388757.61    -387357.8   -68056.853
 .
 .
```

Input_Script:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y1, y2, y3, y4 = [], [],[], [], []

with open("initial.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        cols = line.split()

        if len(cols) == 5:
            x.append(float(cols[0]))
            y1.append(float(cols[1]))
            y2.append(float(cols[2]))
            y3.append(float(cols[3]))
            y4.append(float(cols[4]))


plt.subplot(411)
plt.plot(x, y1, '-')
plt.title('initial_output')
plt.ylabel('temperature')

plt.subplot(412)
plt.plot(x, y2, '-')
plt.ylabel('potential')

plt.subplot(413)
plt.plot(x, y3, '-')
plt.ylabel('temperature')

plt.subplot(414)
plt.plot(x, y4, '-')
plt.xlabel('steps')
plt.ylabel('pressure')

plt.savefig("a.jpeg", dpi=100)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: There is no file or link of an image.

Comment: @SpghttCd I have uploaded the image. sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in the end you just need `plt.tight_layout()`. It rearranges a multiplot figure.
Note the optional `rect`-kwarg, which allows for defining an area within the subplots are rearranged, e.g. in order to keep distance to a global figure title (see also example below).

However, if you use `numpy` anyway, you do not need to import a text file manually. Use e.g. `genfromtxt`:

```
data = np.genfromtxt('initial.txt', names='x', 'temp_1','potential','temp_2', 'pressure'])

array([(  0., 1865.74   , -388642.31, -362596.65, -57421.263),
       (100.,  100.39272, -388659.69, -387258.21, -68103.868),
       (200.,  100.34027, -388677.95, -387277.2 , -68090.633),
       (300.,  100.25494, -388696.92, -387297.36, -68081.08 ),
       (400.,  100.28753, -388716.37, -387316.36, -68072.858),
       (500.,  100.27897, -388736.41, -387336.52, -68067.56 ),
       (600.,  100.27288, -388757.61, -387357.8 , -68056.853)],
      dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('temp_1', '<f8'), ('potential', '<f8'), ('temp_2', '<f8'), ('pressure', '<f8')])
```

Then, a convenient way to create multiple plots in one figue is `plt.subplots`. E.g. it has a simple keyword for sharing one x-axis for all subplots:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(4, 1, sharex=True)
fig.suptitle('initial_output')
```

Then just iterate over your data and axes and your done:

```
for ax, lbl in zip(axs, data.dtype.names[1:]):
    ax.plot(data['x'], data[lbl], label=lbl)
    ax.set_ylabel(lbl)

ax.set_xlabel('steps')
fig.tight_layout(rect=[0, 0, 1, .97])
```

Result:

[image]

That all being said: if you want really convenient data import, analysis and plotting, have a look at `pandas`. https://pandas.pydata.org/